# É recomendável usar memset antes de strncpy?

Tags: c, string, concatenação-de-string

Normalmente quando nós queremos copiar o conteúdo de uma determinada *string* para dentro de outra *string* nós podemos utilizar as funções `strncat` ou `strncpy`.

**Usando `strncat`**

O uso de strncat para copiar *strings* é meio que "errado", pois essa função serve para concaternar/juntar *strings* e não copiar, mas mesmo assim é possível e para isso basta usar a função [memset](http://killocan.blogspot.com/2010/02/memset-e-suas-pegadinhas.html) na *string* de destino e logo em seguida aplicar a função `strncat` impedindo assim que a string de destino receba lixo. Segue o código abaixo para uma visão maior da coisa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char foo[15];

    printf("\nFoo (lixo): %s\n", foo);

    memset(foo, 0, 15);

    strncat(foo, "BOING 737", 10);

    printf("\nFoo: %s\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

**Usando `strncpy`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char foo[15];

    printf("\nFoo (lixo): %s\n", foo);

    strncpy(foo, "BOING 737", 10);

    printf("\nFoo: %s\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Agora vem a dúvida: Seria necessário, por motivos de precaução a fim de evitar lixo, usar `memset` antes de `strncpy`?

Answer (score 3):

Não é essa a questão a ser abordada. Nos casos onde o ponteiro poderia ser utilizado contendo lixo, provavelmente a lógica do algoritmo/programa/função está errada, e colocar um `memset` lá não faria com que ela ficasse correta.

Nos casos onde o algoritmo está correto sem usar o `memset` e o lixo nunca é utilizado, então colocar o `memset` lá não vai ajudar em nada.

Nos casos onde sem o `memset`, a lógica está errada e ao acrescentá-lo, ela fica correta, então que assim seja. Neste caso o `memset` está **inicializando** a memória com um monte de zeros. No entanto, não dá para generalizar e dizer que essa seria uma solução universal, embora decerto seja frequente.

Existem casos onde o array deveria ser **inicializado** com alguma outra coisa, tais como espaços em branco ou um texto pré-determinado ou alguma outra coisa. Nesses casos, acrescentar o `memset` provavelmente não vai te ajudar.

No final, a questão se reduz em como essa memória deve ser inicializada. O `memset` é apenas uma das formas de se inicializar, mas não é a única. O algoritmo/programa/função deve garantir que a memória a ser utilizada foi inicializada, mas isso não é motivo para inicializar agressivamente qualquer coisa mesmo se não for necessário.

Quanto a usar `memset`+`strncat` ou `strncpy`, o `strncpy` deve ter um desempenho melhor, mas isso só será mensurável e significativo se estiver dentro de um laço que execute pelo menos algumas milhões de vezes ou se for algo que você use para processar quantidades de textos equivalentes a livros inteiros e que não seja algo que tenha o tempo de processamento dominado por alguma outra operação mais complexa. Ou seja, provavelmente não terá diferença significativa.

No entanto, o principal motivo para usar o `strncpy` é que a sua intenção fica bem mais clara para quem for ler o código (mesmo que seja você mesmo meses ou anos depois). Usar `memset`+`strncat` é algo no mínimo estranho.

Se for realmente necessário zerar todo o *buffer* antes de usá-lo, eu recomendaria usar `memset`+`strncpy`. Mas se não for necessário zerá-lo, bastando que qualquer coisa após o terminador nulo seja ignorada, então o `strncpy` sozinho já seria o suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

A documentação de [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) responde à sua questão.

Citando apenas as partes que interessam:

> If the end of the source C string (...) is found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it

Traduzindo:

> Se a string a ser copiada tiver menos carateres que o tamanho indicado, são colocados zeros no fim até fazer o tamanho.

Estes zeros acabam por fazer de terminador, mesmo que a string original não o tenha, e por isso nunca irá ver nenhum lixo na string, pois as funções que trabalham em strings param no primeiro terminador.

> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (...).

Traduzindo:

> Nenhum caratere terminador é acrescentado no fim do destino, se o tamanho da string for superior à quantidade especificada. E por esse motivo a string resultante não será considerada uma string C terminada com null.

Ou seja:

- Se copiar menos carateres que o tamanho indicado, nunca verá lixo, assumindo que copia uma string válida com terminador.
- Se copiar mais carateres que o tamanho indicado regra geral irá ficar com uma string não terminada e por isso apanha lixo.

Exemplos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    //Teste para copia com menos caracteres que o numero indicado
    char foo2[] = "outra string!!!";
    printf("\nFoo (lixo): %s\n", foo2); //Foo (lixo): outra string!!!
    strncpy(foo2, "BOING 737", 10);
    printf("\nFoo: %s\n", foo2); //Foo: BOING 737

    //Teste para copia com mais caracteres que o numero indicado
    char foo[] = "outra string!!!"; 
    printf("\nFoo (lixo): %s\n", foo); //Foo (lixo): outra string!!!
    strncpy(foo, "BOING 737", 5);
    printf("\nFoo: %s\n", foo); //Foo: BOING string!!!

    return 0;
}
```

Apliquei uma string inicial para tornar os testes mais evidentes.

[Teste você mesmo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/1w8EJq)

Conclusão:

Se tem a certeza que está a copiar uma string completa(com terminador) e o tamanho é inferior ou igual ao indicado no `strncpy` então não precisa de fazer `memset`. Se não tem a certeza disto o melhor é jogar pelo seguro e aplicar o `memset`.

Vale lembrar que grande parte, se não mesmo todas as funções de leitura, tais como `scanf`, colocam o terminador na string lida, tornando desnecessário fazer qualquer tipo de `memset` de antemão.